# Why am I unable to "Test Drive" applications in the Software Center?

Tags: 11.04, testdrive

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 Beta. One of the new features that I've seen being advertised is the ability to ["Test Drive" an application](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/ubuntu-software-center-lets-you-test.html).

I wanted to try this out so I installed qtnx like so: `sudo apt-get install qtnx`. However once I went back into the Software Center it did not give me the option to test drive an app. The only buttons that showed up were More Info and Install. Clicking More Info just display a longer description and another install button.

How can I enable the "Test Drive" feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test Drive is currently limited to only the 30 most popular applications in the Software Center (see the bottom of [this post on OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/03/test-drive-offers-install-free-app-try-outs-in-ubuntu-11-04/)).  If you weren't looking at one of those programs in the Software Center, that would explain why there was no "Test Drive" button.